# Which Design pattern for dynamical creating buttons

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, user-controls

I have created a custom user control that adds combo boxes to itself.

My custom user control has 1 button which Adds Two Combo Boxes.

Clicking on it adds 2 combo boxes under the last two.

When the selected index is changed on any of the combo boxes it will run a calculation using the selected values in each box.

This is my code so far...

```
 public partial class PlateSectionAdder : UserControl
    {

        private List<Dictionary<string, CueComboBox>> listOfTwoCombos = new List<Dictionary<string, CueComboBox>>();

        public List<string> ColList { get; }
        public List<string> PlateList { get; }


        private int count = 1;
        private int gap = 3;
        private int edge = 5;

        private Button btnAdd = new Button();


        public PlateSectionAdder(List<string> collist, List<string> platelist)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ColList = collist;
            this.PlateList = platelist;

            btnAdd.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            btnAdd.Top = edge / 2;
                btnAdd.Left = edge;
                btnAdd.Width = this.Width - (edge * 2);
            btnAdd.Click += BtnAdd_Click;
                this.Controls.Add(btnAdd);
        }

        private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CueComboBox cmbCols = new CueComboBox();
                cmbCols.DataSource = this.ColList;
                cmbCols.Top = (btnAdd.Bottom + edge) * count;
                cmbCols.Left = edge;
                cmbCols.Width = btnAdd.Width / 2 - gap;
            cmbCols.SelectedIndexChanged += CalculatePlateSections;

            CueComboBox cmbPlates = new CueComboBox();
                cmbPlates.DataSource = this.PlateList;
                cmbPlates.Top = (btnAdd.Bottom + edge) * count;
                cmbPlates.Left = cmbCols.Right + gap;
                cmbPlates.Width = btnAdd.Width / 2 - gap;
                cmbCols.DataSource = ColList;


            this.Controls.Add(cmbCols);
            this.Controls.Add(cmbPlates);

            this.Height = btnAdd.Height + (cmbCols.Height * count) + edge + edge + 1;
                cmbCols.DataSource = ColList;
                cmbPlates.DataSource = PlateList;


            cmbPlates.SelectedIndexChanged += CalculatePlateSections;

            count++;
        }

        private void CalculatePlateSections(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
```

The combo boxes seem to be copies of the same instance, rather than independent, I thought by using the new keyword they would be each there own instance.

I am sure there a design pattern out there that would be right for this but not sure which one.

Has a look at the builder pattern but it does not seem exactly what I am looking for.

if there is anything unclear about this let me know and I will clarify.

Comment: What do you mean with "The combo boxes seem to be copies of the same instance, rather than independent"?

Comment: when I change one combo box it changes the others to the same value, so if i change one of the cmbCols boxes it changes all the other cmbCols  boxes.

Comment: I think (bit of a newbie with bindings) that its because all the combos are binded to the same DataSource. I dont know if you can use the same datasource with no binding, but an ugly solution may be setting the datasource to a new copy of your lists

Comment: Yes that makes sense now i need to create a new copy of the data source, however i was really looking for a design pattern which would fit  as I believe the code is as you say a bit ugly.

Comment: Do not overrate "Design Patterns". It is not possible to have "Design Patterns" for each task wich may arise. And sometimes, when to much concentrated on the design patterns, you fit your problem to the pattern instead of write code to solve your current task. When I was a young programmer (decades ago), knowing only a few tools, an experienced developer told me: If you only have a hammer (= know some of your favorite patterns), every problem looks like a nail. The GOF patterns do not cover all possible problems in programming.

Comment: Another point I want to say: In a projcet team we had a team lead, who included features only because "there is a interesting design pattern we could use". There ar more negative experiences with patterns. "Short" conclusion: Write readable code, if it works who cares if you use a "pattern".

Comment: Thanks I will take note and i guess try and stick to S.O.L.I.D as I re write this.

Comment: To add to @nabuchodonossor's answer, the justification for using a pattern should emerge from your code, not forced onto it.